# Modify vscode `workspaceStorage` folder path

Tags: visual-studio-code

The default workspaceStorage storage path is `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage`.

It takes up a lot of disk space, so I want to know how to modify this default storage path.

Comment: I have read issues [#1404](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1404) [#22557](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22557), but  I still don't know how to simply change the workspaceStorage path.    If there is a simple way of operation, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Workaround:
`code --user-data-dir <some dir>`

See this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22557

Comment: Note that the `--user-data-dir` sets the path for _all_ user-data (as you would expect) - this is more than just the `workspaceStorage` (a sub-subdirectory of the user-data). So, from the default storage path, this refers to the `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Code` directory and everything below.