# How does VSCode determine the workspaceStorage folder for a given workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**NOTE: This SO post asks a different question: [Modify vscode `workspaceStorage` folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187662/modify-vscode-workspacestorage-folder-path)**

VSCode generates a unique ID for each workspace, then uses the folder `~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/<ID>` to store settings for that workspace.

How can I find this ID from an external script? The most obvious method seems to be scanning `~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/` until I find the correct folder, but that might be slow for computers with lots of workspaces.

Comment: I would think simply checking to see if the <ID> directory exists in your script would be plenty fast enough.  If you know it exists, you should then be able to perform whatever it is you are looking for afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A description to get the `<ID>` part of the `~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/<ID>` path for VSCode workspace folders is found in the source: [vscode/src/vs/platform/resource/node/resourceIdentityServiceImpl.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/cadabab73fef89fe0c4bfe23b5a33cd58e39ea9c/src/vs/platform/resource/node/resourceIdentityServiceImpl.ts#L30-L53)

The interesting part (for Linux) being:

```js
ctime = fileStat.ino;
// we use the ctime as extra salt to the ID so that we catch the case of a folder getting
// deleted and recreated. in that case we do not want to carry over previous state
return createHash('md5').update(resource.fsPath).update(ctime ? String(ctime) : '').digest('hex');
```

(note: actual ctime or rather birthtime in milliseconds is used on MacOS and Windows)

In a script you would need to get the inode number (or ctime if not on Linux) then send both path and that number through `md5sum`.

### Example Linux

```sh
$ stat -c "%i" /your/workspace/path/here
7501991
$ echo -n /your/workspace/path/here7501991 |md5sum
390bd26c245c78dd693b7c16b7cfe36a
```

### Example MacOS

```sh
$ stat -f "%.3FB" /your/workspace/path/here
1684939372.000
$ echo -n /your/workspace/path/here1684939372000 |md5
ac4bb3fec841e74ea183d46ed53c3cf4
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could not comment yet …

The "Example Linux" from @zany's reply contains a small typo. `stat` should be called with the option **-c** instead of **-f**.

```
$ stat -c "%i" /your/workspace/path/here
1275310155
```

Comment: You are of course right :) Typo corrected.

Answer (score 0):

For remote workspaces, it computes the hash [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/442419c7a24beda953fe229ede17cef870c0ac9a/src/vs/platform/workspaces/node/workspaces.ts#L51-L54):

```js
        // Remote: produce a hash from the entire URI
        if (folderUri.scheme !== Schemas.file) {
            return createHash('md5').update(folderUri.toString()).digest('hex');
        }
```

The URI can be found in `.config/Code/User/globalStorage/storage.json`, see "*folderUri*" there, e.g.:

```json
"folderUri": "vscode-remote://dev-container%..."
```

To compute the hash:

```bash
$ echo -n "vscode-remote://dev-container%..." | md5sum
72bbae87ffdad5631fd3b0caf81b79cb  -
```

Alternatively, for any workspaces, the hash can be seen in the verbose output,
see *"workspace:"* strings there:

```bash
$ code --verbose | grep workspace:
    workspace: { id: '72bbae87ffdad5631fd3b0caf81b79cb', uri: [$] },
...
```